# Getting the current time and date on a 24 hour timescale

Tags: java, android, date, time

I am having problems getting the current time on a 24 hour timescale. As far as I know, "HH" should represent the current hour on a 24 hour timescale, however, for some reason, "HH" is not interpreted at all. This is why the following line of code outputs something like *"HH:50:06 Uhr, 02. Sep."*:

```
DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss 'Uhr', dd. MMM", new Date());
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Using "hh" works, however, this will output the time on a 12 hour scale, which is not what I'd like to do.

Help's appreciated!

Comment: Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#HOUR_OF_DAY I hope it will help you!

Comment: On format characters from the link from Dimitris Makris: “Up to API level 17, only `adEhkMmszy` were supported. Note that this class incorrectly implements `k` as if it were `H` for backwards compatibility.” This seems to explain why uppercase `H` came through as `H`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) to format it the way you like, this works:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String str = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Also [Android version of docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 7):

`HH` is the format specifier for hour of the day in the 24-hour format (0-23; with an offset of 0) only when you utilize the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class for formatting dates.

You are using the [`format` method of the `android.text.format.DateFormat` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#format%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.util.Date%29) class, that does not employ this notation; instead it uses the symbol [`k`/`kk`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) for displaying hours in the 24-hour format.
Therefore, your date format string must be specified in the following manner:

```
DateFormat.format("kk:mm:ss 'Uhr', dd. MMM", new Date());
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on this.

Comment: This is unfortunate, given that the Javadoc at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html states "For the canonical documentation of format strings, see SimpleDateFormat."

Comment: @RobertTupelo-Schneck, yes, it is not evident that the canonical documentation applies only when you use the factory methods of the class and not to the others when you supply your own format strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
      String s = sdf.format(new Date());
```