# Calendar.getInstance() gives me wrong time depends when I am asking

Tags: java, android, calendar

While in the morning I used same code, it gives me correct hour. But afternoon it is less 12 hours.

For example at 11:21 I would receive 11:21, but at 15:22 it would be 03:22.

My code:

```
@OnClick(R.id.createMeetingTime)
void onClickTime() {
    // To show current time in the time picker
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR); 
    int minute = currentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    String time = mTime.getText().toString();
    if(! time.equals("")) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        try {
            currentTime.setTime(format.parse(time));
            hour = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            minute = currentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    TimePickerDialog timePicker;
    timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(
            CreateMeetingActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("00");
            mTime.setText(numberFormat.format(selectedHour) + ":" +
                    numberFormat.format(selectedMinute));

            mDateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
            mDateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
        }
    },hour,minute, true); // 24h format
    timePicker.setTitle("Choose Time");
    timePicker.show();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: 15:22 is 03:22 PM. Check if you date is AM or PM.

Comment: it is using  24 h system - 3rd line before end - true for 24h

Comment: The HH looks to be the right specifier for 24-hour time, so I suspect that the input to SimpleDateFormat got messed up prior to using it.  The code looks overly complex for what you're trying to do, so try simplifying it.  A variation on this solution might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280745/getting-the-current-time-and-date-on-a-24-hour-timescale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Calendar.HOUR` is the field for a 12-hour clock. Use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` for a 24-hour clock version.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR

Comment: thanks a lot. I do now about it, but somehow missed it in my code.