# Android java get current time in 24 hours format

Tags: java, android, time, calendar

I am trying to get the current time in 24 hours format by using the code below:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int currentMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

System.out.println(currentHour);
System.out.println(currentMinute);
```

My current time is 3.11PM Singapore time. But then when I execute the code above, I am getting 7.09. Any ideas?

Comment: Use HOUR_OF_DAY instread of HOUR

Comment: @AntonA. that still doesnt match the output given that at least the minutes are actually matching

Comment: @XtremeBaumer are you sure you phone time does not equal output?

Comment: @AntonA. I am not the OP. But looking at the given hours, his code should actually output `3:11` and not `7:09` or `7:11`

Comment: Check the default Locale, or do `getInstance(new Locale("CN"))` or what fits for Singapore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the current time and date on a 24 hour timescale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280745/getting-the-current-time-and-date-on-a-24-hour-timescale)

Comment: @ADM It is not duplicate. I tried that as well but the hour is wrong, just that the minute is correct

Comment: @dummygg, you need to check the default timezone value, TimeZone.getDefault().

Comment: @Ankur I tried with this: Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); But I am still getting the wrong hour :(

Comment: Its clearly a duplicate . You need to check few things `TimeZone` and `DeviceTime`. You are getting time as per UK TimeZONE See the difference in GMT . Cause Singapore is  on ` (GMT+8) ` and UK in on ` (GMT-0) `

Comment: Locale isn’t relevant. Time zone is. The two are unrelated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either. I get 9 and 43, which agrees with my computer clock.

Comment: @dummygg, you would get different value as GMT is not the timezone for singapore, i guess. I asked you to check the default timezone. But you can also try "Asia/Singapore" in place of "GMT" to get your time according to Singapore

Answer (score 3):

I figured the solution already:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8"));
currentHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
currentMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

The code above returns exactly what I wanted

Comment: I recommend `Asia/Singapore` over `GMT+8`.

Comment: i didnt give any time zone. but got exact hour

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the time in 24 hr format

```
public String getFormattedTime() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    return dateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Comment: But the hour returned was wrong, the minute was correct though

Comment: Try this method. Hope it works "String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date()).toString();"

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class as the first option or without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). Also your code won’t solve the asker’s issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t be sure from the information you have provided, but the likely cause is that your JVM’s time zone setting is UTC. If you ran your program at, say, 15:09:55 Singapore time, that would print as 7 and 9 in UTC. If you then read your clock in Singapore time a little over a minute later, or read it from a clock that wasn’t in perfect synch with your device (or simulator), it would show 3:11 PM.

The JVM usually picks up its time zone setting from the device, but there can be all sorts of reasons why it is getting it from somewhere else.

As Anton A. said in a comment, you need `HOUR_OF_DAY` instead of `HOUR` for 24 hour format (though the time was 7:09 AM in UTC, so this error wasn’t the cause of the unexpected hour in your case).

**java.time**

The modern way to print the current time is:

```
    System.out.println(LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore")));
```

The `Calendar` class that you were using is long outdated and poorly designed. `LocalTime` is the class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, that represents the time of day (without time zone, but the `now` method accepts a time zone to initialize to the current time in that zone). If your Android device is less than new (under API level 26), you will need [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/blob/master/build.gradle) in order to use it. See [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

One more link: [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.